# Menu fixo está com links desativados

Tags: html, jquery, css

Acesse o site que estou fazendo: https://testando23.000webhostapp.com/. Clique na seta verde, perceba que nesse menu fixo que surgiu os dois links (home e sobre) estão desativados, mas se você descer mais a página os links se ativam de novo, e se clicar no botão "ver mais", na outra página eles se ativam também.

Percebi que os links só ficam desativados quando existe conteúdo na página.

Alguém sabe o que tá acontecendo?

header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-PmY9l28YgO4JwMKbTvgaS7XNZJ30MK9FAZjjzXtlqyZCqBY6X6bXIkM++IkyinN+" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-vhJnz1OVIdLktyixHY4Uk3OHEwdQqPppqYR8+5mjsauETgLOcEynD9oPHhhz18Nw" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mostramenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mudaseta.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/desliza.js"></script>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['topicos']))
        {
            $temp = explode('/',$_GET['topicos']);
            $pgatual = strtolower(end($temp));
        }
        else
        {
            $pgatual = "";
        }
    ?>
    <title>DC David Cesar | <?php $pagatual; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="head row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-7">
            <a href="index?topicos=nav/home"><img height="66" src="imagens/logo2.png"></a>
            <h1>David Cesar</h1>
            <h2>Programador Web</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5">
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index?topicos=nav/home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index?topicos=nav/sobre">Sobre</a></li>
                    <li>Trabalho</li>
                    <li>Contato</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

home.php:

```
<div id="top" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
        </div>
        <div id="logo" class="col-lg-6">
            <img height="188.6" src="imagens/logo1.png"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
        </div>
        <div id="seta" class="col-lg-2">
            <img src="imagens/seta1.png" id="st"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
        </div>
        <div id="conhecimentos" class="col-lg-8">
            <p>Conhecimentos em HTML5, CSS3, PHP7, Mysql, Javascript, Jquery, Bootstrap, Wordpress, design responsivo, Gimp e Inkscape.</p></br>
            <form name="form" action="index.php?topicos=nav/sobre" method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">LER MAIS</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header .head
{
    position:fixed;left:15px;width:100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#top").mouseenter(function()
    {
        $(".head").animate({top:"-95"});
    });
    $("#top").mouseleave(function()
    {
        $(".head").animate({top:"0"});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div com o conteúdo que vem após o menu está sobrepondo parcialmente o `head`, cobrindo os links:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode resolver isso adicionando a propriedade `z-index` com um valor `1` ou maior no estilo `header .head`:

```
header .head {
    position: fixed;
    left: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

O `z-index` fará com que o `head` fique acima do resto do conteúdo. É preciso aprender como funciona a organização de pilhagem dos elementos. Pode dar uma conferida [nesta documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).